# Should I store or reference a third parties API response?

Tags: api

So bit of background, I have an api which will return some basic details about a song (title, duration, artist_id) what I want to do is within this response either return or reference more information about the song as a child element which you request or is added to the request. This will come from difference sources e.g soundcloud, youtube, spotify etc etc.

Basically my question is should I store the response from each source e.g soundcloud, youtube, spotify etc etc or should I store a link to the relevant api which the consumer of my API can they request ?

I would rather store the response to cut down on additional HTTP requests.

Any help would be great.